# Appcelerator Platform Application Environments

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

Appcelerator Platform Dashboard lists `Environments` -> `Development` & `Production` for each app.

What are these environments and how to set each apps environment while building from Appcelerator Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default:

- Simulator: Development
- Device: Test
- Ad Hoc / Enterprise / App Store / Google Play: Production

But you can override:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference